# php how to apply the same code to various arrays with loop functions?

Tags: php, arrays, search, loops

i'm new here and i'm learning php now and i don't have a clue of mysql.

i want to do a little script that scans various arrays for the presence of a value and returns some values according to the fact that they're there or not

i've done this:

```
<?php
$array1=array("a","b","c","d");
$array2=array("e","f","g","h");
$array3=array("g","f","e","d");

for($counter=1;$counter<4;$counter++)
{echo ''.in_array("d",$array$counter);}
?>
```

this isn't working, i get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in ... on line 7" but if i write:

```
<?php
$array1=array("a","b","c","d");
$array2=array("e","f","g","h");
$array3=array("g","f","e","d");

for($counter=1;$counter<4;$counter++)
{echo ''.in_array("d",$array1);}
?>
```

i get 111 as the output so the loop, echo and in_array are working fine and the area that's giving the error is the "$array$counter".

is there a way to fix this? 
is there another way to increment an array inside loop functions? 
is there another way of achieving what i want in a simple way?

thanks in advance and i hope someone can help me because i've searched for hours now and came up with nothing.

Comment: Well, to fix the first one, you could do `$GLOBALS['array'.$counter]` instead of `$array$counter`. But I'm not sure what you're second question means, and because I'm not sure what you "want," I don't know how to answer the third one.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc i said what i wanted at the beginning of the post. my second question means that the number that the array name happens to have on it should go up in the same way as the number of loops without making the script not work. but it has been answered already so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
$array1=array("a","b","c","d");
$array2=array("e","f","g","h");
$array3=array("g","f","e","d");

for($counter=1;$counter<4;$counter++)
{
  $varName = 'array'.$counter;
  echo (int)in_array("d",$$varName);
}
```

Comment: it works perfectly and that's exactly what i wanted. i'm not saying other methods posted here don't work but instead of creating a whole new way you altered my way in a way that it works and that keeps the simplicity of the script, thank you.